# Moving ASP.NET MVC project folder in VS 2013 changes System.Web.Mvc version to 4.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When starting a new Web Application empty MVC project in VS 2013 using .NET 4.5.2, initially, VS 2013 will be referencing Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.1.2 which contains System.Web.Mvc 5.1.0. But I typically change the directory of the MVC project so I remove the project from the solution, change the directory of the project using Windows Explorer, and then add the existing project again in the solution using VS 2013.

However, upon doing this, when I look on the version of System.Web.Mvc, it is now changed to 4.0.0. I've checked the repositories.config and it has the correct path for packages.config of the project. The packages config on the project also contains version="5.1.2" although the referenced System.Web.Mvc is 4.0.0.

Furthermore, as I am trying to use IAuthenticationFilter, the interface cannot be detected by Intellisense anymore (with red squiggly line) but I can still compile and run!

Do you guys know any workaround for this? I can use NuGet to update MVC to the latest (5.2.2 I think) and the reference would be fixed but I want to use the default 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can target a specific version of MVC using the Nuget Package Manager Console:

Go to

> Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manage Console

At the prompt you can type

> update-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -version 5.1.2

I believe this is the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve. You may need to remove existing references to the MVC and WebPages dlls, sometimes references stick when moving from local/GAC references to those determined by nuget.

Comment: you can also reinstall the package: **Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -reinstall**

Comment: Hi Carl, reinstalling worked, it just added some extra dll i've not originally used but those can be removed. Thanks!